# VBA sub program must run twice to properly update dependent cell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am writing a program in VBA-excel that is supposed to:
1 - determine how much data is in an array (dynamic array)
2 - based on the number inside the first array, (1 through 3) do a certain calculation (volume of cylinder = 1, volume of cone = 2, and volume of a section of sphere = 3)
3 - based off the number in the first array, the volume is to be printed in column D with the correct calculation

My current program does all of this just fine

The next step is to keep a running total of how many 1's, 2's, and 3's I have (and print them out) and to also keep a running total of each shapes total volume. (i.e. the total volume for all cylinders = xxxx)

again this all updates just fine except the running total of the volumes. the problem I am having is after I run the program once and existing values are in there, i change a number (in any one of the columns) and i have to run the program twice in order to get the correct data to output to the running total volumes.

What I think is happening is the volume in column D (the calculated volume) is not updating before the  running total volume takes the number. but in looking at my code i do not understand why the running total volume retrieves that number before the new calculation happens.

Any thoughts on how i could postpone the running total until all the data is populated and then gather all the data?

Here is my current code:

```
Sub volumecalc()

totalnum = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:A1000"))

ReDim Array1(1 To totalnum)
For i = 1 To totalnum
    Array1(i) = Cells(i + 1, 1)
Next i


ReDim array2(1 To totalnum)
For j = 1 To totalnum
    array2(j) = Cells(j + 1, 2)
Next j


ReDim array3(1 To totalnum)
For k = 1 To totalnum
    array3(k) = Cells(k + 1, 3)
Next k

ReDim array4(1 To totalnum)
For p = 1 To totalnum
    array4(p) = Cells(p + 1, 4)
Next p

Range("D2:D1000") = Clear
Range("G2:G4") = Clear
Range("H2:H4") = Clear


totalvol = 0
totalvol1 = 0
totalvol2 = 0
Count = 0
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

For i = 1 To totalnum

        If Array1(i) = 1 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Pi * array2(i) ^ 2 * array3(i)
            Count = Count + 1
            Cells(2, 7) = Count
            totalvol = totalvol + array4(i)
            Cells(2, 8) = totalvol
        ElseIf Array1(i) = 2 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 4) = (WorksheetFunction.Pi * array2(i) ^ 2 * array3(i)) / 3
            count1 = count1 + 1
            Cells(3, 7) = count1
            totalvol1 = totalvol1 + array4(i)
            Cells(3, 8) = totalvol1
        ElseIf Array1(i) = 3 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 4) = (WorksheetFunction.Pi * array2(i) ^ 2 * array3(i)) / 2 + (WorksheetFunction.Pi * array3(i) ^ 3) / 6
            count2 = count2 + 1
            Cells(4, 7) = count2
            totalvol2 = totalvol2 + array4(i)
            Cells(4, 8) = totalvol2

        ElseIf Array1(i) < 1 Or Array1(i) > 3 Then
            MsgBox ("Not In Correct Range, Try Again")
        End If
Next i

For j = 1 To totalnum
    If array2(j) <= 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Number Must Be Greater Than 0")
    End If
Next j

For j = 1 To totalnum
    If array3(j) <= 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Number Must Be Greater Than 0")
    End If
Next j


Cells(5, 7) = Count + count1 + count2
Cells(5, 8) = totalvol + totalvol1 + totalvol2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is reading the values from column D into array4. Newly calculated values are then written into column D but the various total volume variables get updated with the values from array4. This is why the totals end up with the old values initially and why things work correctly when the program runs again (because array4 gets updated with the new values).

It's not really clear why array4 is needed so just replace the occurrences of:

```
totalvol = totalvol + array4(i)
```

with:

```
totalvol = totalvol + Cells(i + 1, 4).Value
```

Comment: That was perfect! I didn't realize I could just add the value of the cell rather than look for the new calculated value in array4. Thank you very much!